# Linked List based question

Tags: rfid

I am making a Smart Cart using RFID. The user will
have a RFID card. As soon as he swipes the card on
the RFID Reader it will identify the user and will create
a linked list for that particular user. The linked list will
contain the unique Rfid based Ids of the items purchased by the user. In my code
the problem is that after the detection of the user it is
not creating any linked list for the items/it is not detecting the items bought by the user. Both the user and items are identified by their unique ids (ie RFID tags).It is detecting the user but once the user is being detected it is not mapping the items bought with that user.

the code for the same is :

```
int count = 0; // count = 0
int i;
char input[12];                                   // character array of size 12 
boolean flag = 0;
// flag =0

boolean comparetag(char x[12], char bb[12]) {
  boolean ff = false;
  int fg = 0;
  for (int cc = 0; cc < 12; cc++) {
    if (x[cc] == bb[cc]) {
      fg++;
    }
  }
  if (fg == 12) {
    ff = true;
  }
  return ff;
}

struct Node {
  char x[12];
  struct Node *next;
};

struct Node* X;
struct Node* point;

void printList(struct Node *n) {
  while (n != NULL) {
    Serial.print(n->x);
    n = n->next;
  }
}

struct Node* Shopping(char[]) {

  Serial.print(input);
  // Print RFID tag number 
  Serial.print("Welcome User");
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Start Shopping ");

  struct Node* head = NULL;
  head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  return head;

}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (flag == 0) {
    if (Serial.available()) {
      count = 0;
      while (Serial.available() && count < 12) // Read 12 characters and store them in input array
      {
        input[count] = Serial.read();
        count++;
        delay(5);
      }

      if (comparetag(input, "1B006AFA9F14")) {
        flag = 1;

        point, X = Shopping(input);
      } else {
        Serial.println("not Registered User");
      }
    }
  } else {
    int c = 0;
    if (Serial.available()) {
      while (Serial.available() && c < 12) // Read 12 characters and store them in input array
      {
        Serial.print("Taking Input");
        X->x[c] = Serial.read();
        c++;
        delay(5);
      }
      struct Node* second = NULL;
      second = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      second = NULL;

      X->next = second;
      X = second;

    }
  }
  printList(point);
}
```

Comment: your question is not related to RFID as the title suggest .... your question is about linked lists .... please update your question title

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any code for making new nodes or linking them into a list. A linked-list needs a root (a known variable that points to the first member of the list); a way to make or acquire new nodes and link them onto the list as the number of items grows; and a way to unlink a node and "discard" it - return its memory - once it is no longer useful.

I'll offer a couple of suggestions for linked-lists, especially in processors like the Uno with limited memory:

1. Don't be tempted to use `malloc()` and `free()` or `new` and `delete` for a system that must run continuously. Allocating and deallocating small pieces of memory, especially when interspersed with other allocation & deallocations, will lead to fragmentation of the heap (that portion of memory used for allocating memory at run-time). The result is that the heap will end up with lots of separate pieces of memory that are free but too small for other allocation requests, so the heap has to acquire more memory to satisfy the larger allocations. It does this by reducing the stack space! Eventually the stack will grow into the heap space, and the program will fail.
   My solution is to define a global array of node structs; enough of them for the program's greatest conceivable need, plus a few more for safety; link them into a list of free nodes; and give new nodes to the application by deallocating one from the free list. A You need link() and unlink() functions for a linked-list anyway, so it takes very little more code to do this.
2. Because we're talking about memory limited processors, If I don't need more than 255 nodes, I link with array indices instead of pointers, saving one byte per node. This costs a little bit more code to index into an array than to de-reference a pointer but compilers have gotten pretty smart about minimizing even that overhead.